# Azure Mobile Apps with ASP.NET Identity or Custom Authorisation

Tags: asp.net-identity, azure-mobile-services

I am evaluating Azure's Mobile Apps and I want to clarify my findings.

A generic mobile app on an app store that targets a wide audience (100,000 customer or more) usually supports a native registration/authorisation and additional one(s) such as Facebook and/or Twitter.

Azure Mobile Apps do not support ASP.NET Identity or Custom Authorisation, they support FB, Twitter, Microsoft, Google and Azure AD.

Is Custom Authorisation support or ASP.NET Identity support coming soon or is there any recommended way of supporting the above scenario (a native registration)? Is there any workaround for now?

Comment: StackOverflow is targeted at technical questions and solutions. For specific feature requests, etc., please use a communication vehicle specific to the product in question. In this case, the Azure Mobile forums would be appropriate: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/home?forum=azuremobile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can use ASP.NET Identity or any other custom scheme. Please refer to this documentation: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-dotnet-backend-how-to-use-server-sdk/#custom-auth/

Comment: it is good idea to use ASP.NET Identity? Or would you recommend something else? Thank you.